# Why did Dante say "LO tuo volume"?

Tags: grammar, articles, orthography

Shouldn't the Poet say *che m'ha fatto cercar IL tuo volume* ? Or is it that at that time there was not definite distinction between *il* and *lo* ?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Nice question to celebrate the 700th anniversary of the Poet's death.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right to note that in contemporary Italian only *il* can be used before a consonant, and the ending of the preceding word is irrelevant. However the rules regarding the usage of *il* vs *lo* have changed in the intervening centuries. From Rohlfs *Grammatica storica della lingua italiana e dei suoi dialetti*, paragraph 414 (my translation)

> In ancient times the usage of the various forms [of the article] was partially more free, and moreover there were some additional forms available. Compared to *il*, *lo* had a wider usage than today. Originally, the two forms were determined by the phonetics of the sentence. The first (even in the [apheretic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apheresis_(linguistics)) form *'l*) was originally used only after a vowel ending, before a simple consonant, while *lo* was used after any ending and before any initial. [...]
>
> Originally only *lo* could be used at the beginning of a sentence. [...] Even much later *lo* was often used after *r* [...]; usage that survived in the expressions *per lo più*, *per lo meno*, *per la meglio*.

Therefore, in the period when Dante was writing, one could not use *il* (or even *'l*) after *cercar*, since the latter word ended with a consonant. Thus he used the form *lo*.